# An hyperlink opens a new tab that closes itself as soon as the intended page appears

Tags: php, frontend

This problem is with our order management system. Clicking view order button as seen in the screenshot below goes to a new tab that stays a few seconds and closes abruptly. Not sure why this strange behavior even when opening this application in firefox comes up.

Pasted the HTML content for view button for you to see if there is anything wrong. Thank you.

```
    <td align="center"><a href="view_order.php?id=95243&amp;name=&amp;po_number=&amp;from_date=12/12/2020&amp;to_date=01/11/2021&amp;vendor=&amp;sku=&amp;phone=&amp;zip=&amp;email=&amp;city=&amp;country=&amp;shipping_mode=&amp;order_status=&amp;item_status=&amp;payment_type=&amp;sortby=order_date&amp;orderby=desc&amp;order_index=0"><img src="img/view.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="View"></a></td>
```

[image]

**view_order.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
    <title>POMS - Reflect Perfection, &nbsp;View Order</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link href="postyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
    <link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="mobile2.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/jq-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    
    
    <!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
    behavior: url(csshover.htc);
    font-size: 100%;
    }
    #menu ul li {float: left; width: 100%;}
    #menu ul li a {height: 1%;}
    #menu a, #menu h2 {
    font: bold 1em/1.6em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    #menu ul ul li {float: right; width: 95%; }
    </style>
    
    <![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript">
    function chkheight(){
        var layerCol1 = document.getElementById("col1");
        var layerCol2 = document.getElementById("col2");
        if((layerCol1) && (layerCol2)){
            var col1height = layerCol1.offsetHeight;
            var col2height = layerCol2.offsetHeight;
            if(col1height > col2height){
                layerCol2.style.height=col1height;
            }
            if(col2height > col1height){
                layerCol1.style.height=col2height;
            }
        }
    }
    
    function color_flags(){
        xw=window.open("/color_flags.php","zz","width=700,height=500");
    }
    </script>
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/source/placeholder.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="includes/view_order.js?v=5"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("input[placeholder]").placeholder();
        $('#headerMenu li:has(ul)').hover(
            function() {
                $('ul', this).css('display', 'block');
            },
            function() {
                $('ul', this).css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
    </script>
    
    </head>
    <body onLoad="chkheight();">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="printheader">Reflect Perfection Inc.: PO Management System</div>
        <div class="headerrow" style="padding: 5px 0;">
            <div style="margin-bottom: 3px;" class="ui-helper-clearfix">
                <ul id="topMenu">
                    <li style="padding-left: 15px;font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: bold;">View Order</li>
                                                                </ul>
                <span id="headerExtra" style="float: right;margin:0 10px 0 0">Pramod | <a href="javascript:color_flags()">Colors &amp; Codes</a> | <a href="index.php?form_action=logout">Logout</a></span>
            </div>
            <div id="headerMenu">
                <ul>
                                    <li class="headerMenu">  <a href="home.php">Home</a>                      </li>
                                    <li class="headerMenu">                     Orders
                                                                <ul>
                                                                            <li>  <a href="search_results.php?from_date=01/12/2021&to_date=01/12/2021">Today</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="search_results.php?from_date=01/11/2021&to_date=01/11/2021">Yesterday</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="search_results.php?from_date=01/05/2021&to_date=01/12/2021">7 Days</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="search_results.php?from_date=12/29/2020&to_date=01/12/2021">14 Days</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="search_results.php?from_date=12/13/2020&to_date=01/12/2021">30 Days</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="search_results.php?order_status=NP&from_date=12/16/2014&to_date=01/12/2021">Not Placed</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="search_results.php?order_status=PL&from_date=12/16/2014&to_date=01/12/2021">Not Shipped</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="flagged_orders.php">Flagged</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="search_orders.php">Advanced Search</a>  </li>
                                                                        </ul>
                         </li>
                                    <li class="headerMenu">  <a href="search_orders.php">Order Search</a>                      </li>
                                    <li class="headerMenu">                     Communications
                                                                <ul>
                                                                            <li>  <a href="email_log.php">Email Log</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="incomingfaxes.php">Incoming Faxes</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="file_log_report.php">Faxes Pending / Today</a>  </li>
                                                                        </ul>
                         </li>
                                    <li class="headerMenu">                     Lookups
                                                                <ul>
                                                                            <li>  <a href="skulookup.php">SKU</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="giftcards.php">Gift Cards</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="promocodes.php">Promo Codes</a>  </li>
                                                                        </ul>
                         </li>
                                    <li class="headerMenu">                     Maintenance
                                                                <ul>
                                                                            <li>  <a href="select_back_order_vendor.php">Clear Vendor Back Orders</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="list_back_order_items.php">Back Order</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="list_inventory.php">Inventory</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="list_vendors.php">Vendors</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="list_system_info.php">System</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="list_users.php">Users</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="php_fast_cache.php?command=clean">Clear Cache</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="php_fast_cache.php?command=stats">Cache Statistics</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="isku_to_sku.php">Rebuild sku_isku File</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="amazon_nodes_add.php">Amazon Nodes</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="sort_cms_attributes.php">CMS Attribute Sort</a>  </li>
                                                                        </ul>
                         </li>
                                    <li class="headerMenu">  <a href="select_report.php">Reports</a>                                         <ul>
                                                                            <li>  <a href="cctransactions.php">CC Transactions</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="list_attention_orders.php?report_type=missing_invoices&new=1">Missing Invoice</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="missing_skus.php">Missing SKUs</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="list_attention_orders.php?report_type=overdue_shipping&new=1">Overdue Shipping</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="list_attention_orders.php?report_type=overdue_rtv&new=1">RTVs Overdue</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="list_attention_orders.php?report_type=pending_refund&new=1">RTVs with Refund Pending</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="poms_email.php">Sent Emails</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="search_results.php?order_status=PL&item_status=PL&from_date=12/16/2014&to_date=01/11/2021">Shipping Notices Not Sent</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="list_shipping_rates.php">Shipping Rates</a>  </li>
                                                                        </ul>
                         </li>
                                    <li class="headerMenu">                     External
                                                                <ul>
                                                                            <li>  <a href="/pm/" target="_blank" >CMS</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="http://dev.perfectmakeupmirrors.com" target="_blank" >Trac Dev</a>  </li>
                                                                        </ul>
                         </li>
                                    <li class="headerMenu">                     Account
                                                                <ul>
                                                                            <li>  <a href="edit_mail_signature.php">Change Email Signature</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="change_password.php">Change Password</a>  </li>
                                                                        </ul>
                         </li>
                                    <li class="headerMenu">                     Accounting
                                                                <ul>
                                                                            <li>  <a href="vendor_invoice_entry.php?vendor_type_flag=0">Vendor Invoices</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="vendor_invoice_entry.php?vendor_type_flag=1">Shipping Invoices</a>  </li>
                                                                                                    <li>  <a href="fedex_payments.php">FedEx Payments</a>  </li>
                                                                        </ul>
                         </li>
                                </ul>
                            <form action="search_results.php" method="get" style="display: inline-block;margin: 0;">
                    <input type="search" name="po_number" size="25" placeholder="PO Number" style="margin-left: 5px;"/>
                </form>
                        </div>
        </div>
    
    <script>
    // to limit screen width of vendor list 1/11/18 AB
    var docloc = document.location.href;
    docloc.indexOf("list_vendors")>-1 ? $('#container').css("max-width","1000px") : "";
    docloc.indexOf("search_results.php")>-1 || docloc.indexOf("list_back_order_items")>-1 ? $('#container').css("max-width","1200px") : "";
    </script>
    
    <style>
    .rowsm a {
        color: black;
        border: solid 1px black;
        font: bold 12px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
        padding: 4px;
        background-color: #c6c6c6;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px 0;
    }
    
    .sticky .rowsm {
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
    .MsgBox {
        border: 1px solid;
        margin: 10px auto;
        padding:15px 10px 15px 50px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 10px center;
        width:75%;
    }
    
    .info {
        color: #00529B;
        background-color: #BDE5F8;
    }
    
    #addItem {
        display: none;
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    .addItemButton {
        float: right;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid;
        margin-top: 3px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .messageDetail {
        text-align: left;
    }
    </style>
    
    
    <script>
    var orderNumber = '110118';
    </script>
    <div class="rowsm" align="center">
        <a href="search_orders.php?order_index=0&name=&po_number=&from_date=12/12/2020&to_date=01/11/2021&vendor=&sku=&phone=&zip=&email=&city=&country=&shipping_mode=&order_status=&item_status=&payment_type=&sortby=order_date&orderby=desc" style="background-color:#FFCCFF">Refine Search</a>
        <a href="search_results.php?order_index=0&name=&po_number=&from_date=12/12/2020&to_date=01/11/2021&vendor=&sku=&phone=&zip=&email=&city=&country=&shipping_mode=&order_status=&item_status=&payment_type=&sortby=order_date&orderby=desc" style="background-color:#99FFFF"><< Search Results</a>
        <a href="print_order.php?id=95243" target="_blank" style="background-color:#33FF00">Print PO</a>
        <a href="view_order.php?order_index=0&name=&po_number=&from_date=12/12/2020&to_date=01/11/2021&vendor=&sku=&phone=&zip=&email=&city=&country=&shipping_mode=&order_status=&item_status=&payment_type=&sortby=order_date&orderby=desc&nav_action=next&id=95243" style="background-color:#83A984">&lt;&lt; Earlier PO</a>
        <a href="view_order.php?order_index=0&name=&po_number=&from_date=12/12/2020&to_date=01/11/2021&vendor=&sku=&phone=&zip=&email=&city=&country=&shipping_mode=&order_status=&item_status=&payment_type=&sortby=order_date&orderby=desc&nav_action=prev&id=95243" style="background-color:#83A984">Later PO &gt;&gt;</a>
        <a href="edit_order.php?id=95243&order_index=0&name=&po_number=&from_date=12/12/2020&to_date=01/11/2021&vendor=&sku=&phone=&zip=&email=&city=&country=&shipping_mode=&order_status=&item_status=&payment_type=&sortby=order_date&orderby=desc" style="background-color:#FFFF00">Edit PO</a>
        <a href="resend_vendor_orders.php?id=95243&order_index=0&name=&po_number=&from_date=12/12/2020&to_date=01/11/2021&vendor=&sku=&phone=&zip=&email=&city=&country=&shipping_mode=&order_status=&item_status=&payment_type=&sortby=order_date&orderby=desc" style="background-color:#FFCCCC" >Resend</a>
        <a href="shipping_notice.php?id=95243&order_index=0&name=&po_number=&from_date=12/12/2020&to_date=01/11/2021&vendor=&sku=&phone=&zip=&email=&city=&country=&shipping_mode=&order_status=&item_status=&payment_type=&sortby=order_date&orderby=desc">Send Shipping Notice</a>
        <a href="update_shipping_info.php?id=95243&order_index=0&name=&po_number=&from_date=12/12/2020&to_date=01/11/2021&vendor=&sku=&phone=&zip=&email=&city=&country=&shipping_mode=&order_status=&item_status=&payment_type=&sortby=order_date&orderby=desc" style="font-weight:bold;color:#4D148C;background-color:#E5E5E7">Update Shipping Info</a>
        <a href="upload_shipping_label.php?id=95243" style="font-weight:bold;color:#4C1600;background-color:#FF9900">Upload Shipping Label</a>
        <a href="process_rtv.php?id=95243&order_index=0&name=&po_number=&from_date=12/12/2020&to_date=01/11/2021&vendor=&sku=&phone=&zip=&email=&city=&country=&shipping_mode=&order_status=&item_status=&payment_type=&sortby=order_date&orderby=desc" style="background-color:#CCFFFF">New RTV</a>
        <a href="customer_mail.php?id=95243&order_index=0&name=&po_number=&from_date=12/12/2020&to_date=01/11/2021&vendor=&sku=&phone=&zip=&email=&city=&country=&shipping_mode=&order_status=&item_status=&payment_type=&sortby=order_date&orderby=desc" style="background-color:#0066FF;color:#FFFFFF">Email</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="col3" class="ui-helper-clearfix">
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset id="left">
                <legend>Order Information</legend>
                <table class="table1">
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td width="35%">PO Number</td>
                        <td width="35%">Order Status</td>
                        <td width="30%">Call Center PO</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row4">
                        <td>110118</td>
                        <td>PL</td>
                        <td>No</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td>Order Date</td>
                        <td>Placed Date</td>
                        <td><span style="float: left;">Promo Discount</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row4">
                        <td>Mon Jan 11, 2021, 3:17 PM</td>
                        <td>Mon Jan 11, 2021, 4:00 PM</td>
                        <td>$0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td>Shipping Amount</td>
                        <td>Tax Amount (10%)</td>
                        <td>Grand Total</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row4">
                        <td>0.00</td>
                        <td>6.67</td>
                        <td>73.35</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td>Customer IP</td>
                        <td>Buy Safe</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row4">
                        <td>0.0.0.0</td>
                        <td>No</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td colspan="3">Order Notes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row4">
                        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
            <br />
            <fieldset id="right">
                <legend>Customer Information</legend>
                <table class="table1">
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td width="50%">Customer Name</td>
                        <td width="50%" class="row4">Rick Dimmitt</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td>Day Phone</td>
                        <td>Night Phone</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row4">
                        <td>+1 763-225-9463 ext10054</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td colspan="2">Email Address</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row4">
                        <td colspan="2">rm54rybvnc1cx95@marketplace.amazon.com</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <br />
            <fieldset id="left">
                <legend>Shipping Information</legend>
                <table class="table1">
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td width="30%">Shipping Method</td>
                        <td width="35%" class="row4" class="cellhighlight">Standard Ground</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td>Ship To</td>
                        <td class="row4">Rick Dimmitt</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td>City, State, Zip Code, Country</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row4">
                        <td>7291 Napa Valley LN Apt 108<br /></td>
                        <td>Springdale, AR&nbsp;&nbsp;72762-0792
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td colspan="2">Special Instructions to Vendor</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row4">
                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
            <br />
            <fieldset id="right">
                <legend>Payment Information</legend>
                <table class="table1">
                    <tr id="row3">
                        <td width="30%">Payment Method</td>
                        <td width="35%" class="row4" class="cellhighlight">Amazon Store</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row4">
                        <td style="color: #000;font-weight: bold;">Order Id #</td>
                                                <td class="rp-po">112-6674508-5208212&nbsp;&nbsp;   Reflect Perfection</td>
                                        </tr>
                    <tr id="row4">
                        <td style="color: #000;font-weight: bold;">Commission</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Order Line Items</legend>
                <table id="table2">
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th>Vendor</th>
                        <th>Vendor SKU</th>
                        <th>Item<br />
                          (Pink line: vendor = NO or xx)
                        </th>
                        <th>Qty Sold</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Total Sale</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Vendor Sl #</th>
                        <th>Vendor Inv # -- Date</th>
                        <th>Ship Mode</th>
                        <th>Tracking #</th>
                        <th>Shipped Date</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top" class="row6 vendorSku">
                        <td>JD</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="http://devpoms.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/search/?q=HL856MNC" target="_new">HL856MNC</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>Jerdon 8", 6X/1X  Lighted Vanity Mirror, Nickel, Height 14"</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>66.68</td>
                        <td>66.68</td>
                        <td>Placed</td>
                        <td>1072</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>01/18/21</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
                            <span class="addItemButton">Add Item</span>
                    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Order Line Items - Weight and Dimensions, SKU Cost, Shipping Location</legend>
                <table>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th>Vendor</th>
                        <th>Vendor SKU</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Qty Sold</th>
                        <th>Weight</th>
                        <th>Height</th>
                        <th>Width</th>
                        <th>Length</th>
                        <th>Shipping Mode</th>
                        <th>Shipping Location</th>
                        <th>Unit Cost</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top" class="row6">
                        <td>JD</td>
                        <td>HL856MNC</td>
                        <td>Jerdon 8", 6X/1X  Lighted Vanity Mirror, Nickel, Height 14"</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>5.80</td>
                        <td>8.25</td>
                        <td>12.25</td>
                        <td>17.00</td>
                        <td>Standard</td>
                        <td>Lebanon, TN 37090</td>
                        <td>40.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Order Audit Log</legend>
                <table id="table2">
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th width="15%">Date</th>
                        <th width="20%">Changed By</th>
                        <th width="65%">Conversations, correspondence, and events</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id=row1 valign="top">
                        <td colspan=3 align="center"><b>None</b></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    
    
    </div><!-- end of col3-->
    
    <div id="addItem">
        <form action="view_order.php?id=95243&order_index=0&name=&po_number=&from_date=12/12/2020&to_date=01/11/2021&vendor=&sku=&phone=&zip=&email=&city=&country=&shipping_mode=&order_status=&item_status=&payment_type=&sortby=order_date&orderby=desc" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="95243" />
            <input type="hidden" name="addItem" value="95243" />
            <input name="quantity" size="2" style="text-align: center;" value="1" /> Qty. <input name="sku" placeholder="sku" />
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#messages tr").bind("click", function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('num');
    
            $("#message"+id).dialog('open');
        });
    
        $(".messageDetail").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: '700px',
            modal: true
        });
        window.close(); // closes this window if this is an opened window from the vendor_invoice_entry page.
    });
    </script>
    
            <div id="footer">&copy; 2017-2021 Reflect Perfection Inc.</div>
        </div><!-- end of container-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please post the contents of the view_order.php

Comment: @KenLee added the entire HTML contents for you.

Comment: `window.close(); // closes this window if this is an opened window from the vendor_invoice_entry page.` …? (Not sure what that comment is supposed to mean, because this just closes the window without checking _any_ conditions.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out. I am checking why this was added?

Comment: It helped me. Could you please answer the question so I can accept it as an answer?